# Should I Create Custom Post Types or Taxonomies in Wordpress when default Categories and Tags are presence?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, categories

I am making a News Website. All I want is to categorize my posts (news) according to pre-defined categories such as politics, sports, local, technology like that. When I was searching about **Effective Categorizing in Wordpress**, I found one of the ways **Custom Post Types** and **Taxonomies.** All I could understand is both are same and why using one over another. So, It is bit confusing. So my problems are,

1. What are the benefits they give **than Default Wordpress Categories and tags?**
2. Should I use **Custom Post Type -> Politics** than using **Category ->Politics**?
3. If I should, what are the advantages (and drawbacks) using Custom Post Types and Taxonomies?
4. What can I do using Custom Post Types and Taxonomies that cannot in default Categories and tags?

Thank you in advance for your help and explanation.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What are the benefits they give than Default Wordpress Categories and tags?

There's no real benefit in using any. 
As they present the same thing which is WordPress posts.

- Should I use Custom Post Type -> Politics than using Category ->Politics?

Since you only have one post type which is News I would strongly suggest using just one post type. There's no need to have different post types per category especially as that would extend development time and just make more mess then it is required.

- If I should, what are the advantages (and drawbacks) using Custom Post Types and Taxonomies?

If you would go for Custom Post type per category you would benefit only with cleaner backend - politics posts would be only in politics etc.
**But** that would mean whenever you want to add new category you have to create new custom post type which might become a huge pain...

I would strongly recommend using one Post type( default or custom it's up to you ) and with proper categorisation you could have perfect News web.

- What can I do using Custom Post Types and Taxonomies that cannot in default Categories and tags?

If you want to have more control over your setup, custom post type, taxonomies, URL paths etc. I think it's easier to start over with new custom post type rather then editing existing one. 
Custom post type can support everything that default posts have but you can also remove extra things that you do not require.
e.g. if you don't need featured image, tags etc you can easily remove these

So your function could look like this:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('News', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('News', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'News'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New News'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit News'),
    'new_item' => __('New News'),
    'all_items' => __('All News'),
    'view_item' => __('View News'),
    'search_items' => __('Search News'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No News found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No News found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('News')

  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 
  register_post_type('News',$args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

It all comes down to what are your needs.
If you don't need anything extra from what default post type offers there's no need for you to create new custom post type.

As I already said multiple custom post types would just add extra complexity to the page and templates.

Go for categories and tags.
Note that it would be good decision to use only one Category per post and as many tags you'd like for a proper categorisation.

Comment: Wow..! Very useful answer..! Thank u very much..!! It means that, there is no reason to use custom post types otherwise we have no special needs. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct. I think that default post can give you everything you need. You can create custom categories and tags to filter posts. :)